# How to multiply two pyspark dataframes element wise?

Tags: python, pyspark, data-science

For example:

### dataframe A

| zip | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 7 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | 6 | 9 |

### dataframe B

| zip | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 | 6 |

### Desired result

| zip | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 8 | 7 |
| 3 | 6 | 10 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | 24 | 54 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not enough explanation, but my guess is that you want to multiple dataframe A with dataframe B using the zip key?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a union and the [`product`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.product.html) aggregate function as well (Note: available as of Pyspark 3.2.0). This is especially nice if you have more than 2 dataframes you'd need to combine this way.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import product

df_a  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
(1,1,4,7),
(3,2,5,8),
(2,3,6,9)
  ], ['zip','1','2','3'])

df_b  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
(1,2,2,1),
(3,3,2,1),
(2,1,4,6)
  ], ['zip','1','2','3'])

key = 'zip'
df = df_a.unionByName(df_b)
df.groupBy(key).agg(*[product(c).cast('int').alias(c) for c in df.columns if c != key]).show()


+---+---+---+---+                                                               
|zip|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  8|  7|
|  3|  6| 10|  8|
|  2|  3| 24| 54|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I've taken the sample df's as provided in Luiz Viola's answer.

Comment: Very cool ......

Comment: Hi ScootCork,This looks good but I am trying to do this on a spark dataframes which have 39000 columns and 39000 rows.So do you have any efficient way of multiplying the two spark dataframes of such big sizes in the way which is mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Inputs:

```
df_a  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
(1,1,4,7),
(3,2,5,8),
(2,3,6,9)
  ], ['zip','1','2','3'])

df_b  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
(1,2,2,1),
(3,3,2,1),
(2,1,4,6)
  ], ['zip','1','2','3'])
```

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def multiply_df(df1, df2, join_key):
    
    result = df1.join(df2, join_key)
    cols = [join_key]
    for col in df1.columns:
        if not col == join_key:
            if col not in cols: cols.append(col+'_')
            result = result.withColumn(col+'_',df1[col] * df2[col])
    

    result = result.select([F.col(s).alias(s.replace('_','')) for s in cols])

    return result

multiply_df(df_a, df_b, 'zip').show()

+---+---+---+---+
|zip|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  8|  7|
|  2|  3| 24| 54|
|  3|  6| 10|  8|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Hi Luiz,This looks good but I am trying to do this on a spark dataframes which have 39000 columns and 39000 rows.So do you have any efficient way of multiplying the two spark dataframes of such big sizes  in the way which is mentioned in the question.